# SQL Server - Failed to create additional new column based on first new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting 2 columns and creating an additional column `RPM` based on a category in column `Description`. I then want to create a new column based on `RPM` called `MaxRPM`. If I remove the 3rd line, the command works fine, but doesnt create `MaxRPM`.

I am getting this error: `State 1, Line 1, Invalid column name 'RPM'`.

**SQL Server Command:**

```
select [ID], [Date],
    max(case when Description = 'RPM' then Value end) as RPM,
    max(RPM) over (partition by [ID] order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND current row) as MaxRPM
from [DB].[Table]
where [Date] > '2019-01-01'
group by [ID], [Date]
```

Why am I getting this error when I just created the new column in line two? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below way - as you cannot use an alias to create another column

```
with cte as
(
select [ID], [Date],
    max(case when Description = 'RPM' then Value end) as RPM
    from [DB].[Table]
where [Date] > '2019-01-01'
group by [ID], [Date]
)

select *,max(RPM) over (partition by [ID] order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND current row) as MaxRPM
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 3rd line needs to be removed in Fami's command, otherwise it gives the same error.

```
with cte as
(
select [ID], [Date],
    max(case when Description = 'RPM' then Value end) as RPM
from [DB].[Table]
where [Date] > '2019-01-01'
group by [ID], [Date]
)

select *,max(RPM) over (partition by [ID] order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND current row) as MaxRPM
from cte
```